# iOS 10 bug: UICollectionView received layout attributes for a cell with an index path that does not exist

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, ios10, uicollectionviewlayout

Running my app in a device with iOS 10 I get this error:

*UICollectionView received layout attributes for a cell with an index path that does not exist*

In iOS 8 and 9 works fine. I have been researching and I have found that is something related to invalidate the collection view layout. I tried to implement that solution with no success, so I would like to ask for direct help. This is my hierarchy view:

```
->Table view 
    ->Each cell of table is a custom collection view [GitHub Repo][1]
        ->Each item of collection view has another collection view
```

What I have tried is to insert

```
    [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
```

In the

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
```

of both collection views.

Also I have tried to invalidate layout before doing a reload data, does not work...

Could anyone give me some directions to take?

Comment: Make sure the indexPath of the UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes match the indexPath of the UICollectionViewCell

Answer (score 144, accepted):

This happened to me when number of cells in collectionView changed. Turns out I was missing invalidateLayout after calling reloadData. After adding it, I haven't experienced any more crashes. Apple has made some modifications to collectionViews in iOS10. I guess that's the reason why we are not experiencing same problem on older versions.

Here's my final code:

```
[self.collectionView reloadData];
[self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];

//Swift 4.2 Version
collectionView.reloadData()
collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
```

Comment: It helped, thank you. But does anyone know, why does it help?

Comment: Great answer, solved an issue I've been having for a while with a new iOS 10 app using collection views. Would love to know why this is required though

Comment: It works when the collectionview row count increases. But crashes again when the row count decreases (ie. works fine when 5 columns to 10 columns but crashes when 10 columns to 5 columns).

Comment: Are you sure you're invalidating the layout every time you call reloadData?  Because that's the behavior I saw prior to adding this workaround.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same as @JayMayu. I crash when the count drops.

Comment: @JoshHrach actually this [article](http://jaymayu.com/uicollectionview-and-dynamically-changing-layouts-on-runtime/) helped me. I had to call `self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()` after reload data.

Comment: @JayMayu I've tried that but it still is crashing for certain view controllers in my app. Thanks for trying to help. I appreciate it.

Comment: My number of cells changed and that one line completely resolved my issue   on iOS 10 - thank you so much! Awesome.

Comment: In my case i was using 2 collectionviews in 1 tableview cell. So assigning separate UICollectionViewFlowLayout to each one solved this strange crash.

Comment: This just finally solved my problem, and I would love to know why - any insight?

Comment: Thank you so much its fixed after assigning the different layout for two different collectionview  thank you so much @user1994956

Comment: This appears to only be an issue in iOS 10 and not iOS 11

Answer (score 54):

When you have custom layout, remember to clear cache (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) while overriding prepare func

```
    override func prepare() {
       super.prepare()
       cache.removeAll()
    }
```

Comment: Solved my problem! Thank you!

Comment: Helped me with custom layout! Thanks

Comment: @DaniSDE can you explain how / where I would use this ? Thank you

Comment: @user6520705 In your layout class you should have overriden prepare func, where you're populating  [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] array. This array is your cache for layout attributes. Just clear it on the start of this prepare method.

Comment: And if you have added "Pull-to-Refresh" control like me, you have to make the content height = 0, to make the UI correct.

Comment: Solved my problem with custom layout. <3

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am using a custom collection view layout with pagination and search, clearing the cache solved my issues. I also added contentHeight = 0 after clearing the cache to reset the height.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm not seeing this cache in my custom layout anywhere?

Comment: @airowe
Cache is an array of objects called `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes`, are you creating one? Can you share your code?

Comment: @ArturC This one worked for me, thanks: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45581964/1496693

Comment: @airowe Good to hear that you resolved your problem! :)

Comment: Thank you for this! I tried all the invalidateLayout suggestions from the other answers, but it didn't work. THIS fixed it.  I had a `collectionView.performBatchUpdates` closure where I was deleting an item from my collection and getting the error mentioned in the question. I had been creating a cache in my `prepare` method, and removing all the items from it worked.  Thank you thank you!  (Using Swift 5 and iOS13)

Comment: @N.W I'm so happy that this answer could help you! :)

Answer (score 23):

I also faced this issue with 2 collectionViews in the same view because I added the same UICollectionViewFlowLayout in both collections :

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
collectionView1.collectionViewLayout = layout
collectionView2.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

Of course it crashes on reload data if collectionView1 Data change. If this could help someone.

So you should do this instead

```
let layout1 = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
collectionView1.collectionViewLayout = layout1

let layout2 = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
collectionView2.collectionViewLayout = layout2
```

Comment: Thanks, Its works for me. I am stuck in it from few days. You are awesome :)

Comment: Hey, I am facing some issues I have two collection view One is cltnTools and another is cltnEdits. cltnEdits is appeared whenever user click on any of cell from cltnTools i am facing error with                                reason: 'UICollectionView recieved layout attributes for a cell with an 
index path that does not exist: <NSIndexPath: 0xb141c60> {length = 2, path = 0 - 2}

Comment: that issue is solve using let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
cltnEdits.collectionViewLayout = layout
every things works prefactly but my cltnEdits cells are scrolling vertically but i want horizontal scrolling for my both collectionvies so that i have written this line         layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal for horizontal scroll, then i am facing that error again. could please help me with this? how can i resolve it.

Comment: @KhushbuDesai I don't think the problem comes from setting layout horizontally / vertically, you might have an issue elsewhere when configuring your collectionview's layouts or reloading datas. I need more codes to find out the issue, you should open a question on stackoverflow with more informations ;)

Comment: here is my Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46903770/uicollectionview-received-layout-attributes-for-a-cell-with-an-index-path-that-d?noredirect=1#comment80800301_46903770

Answer (score 6):

Previous answer helps, but if you use autoresizing cells, their size will be incorrect.

```
 UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
 layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSizeMake(60, 25);
 layout.itemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize;             
 self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout;
```

I solve this issues by replacing

```
[self.collectionView reloadData];
```

to

```
[self.collectionView reloadSections:indexSet];
```

Answer (score 6):

The @Katrin's answer helped a lot, but I could achieve even better results by adding one more line:

```
collectionView.reloadData()
collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
collectionView.layoutSubviews() // <-- here it is :)
```

I can't now say if I could reproduce crash with this line or not, but I guess there was one... So, still not a silver bullet, but something.

Comment: Not a good advice actually. You should not call ````layoutSubviews()```` directly. If you want to force a layout update, call the ````setNeedsLayout()```` method instead to do so prior to the next drawing update. If you want to update the layout of your views immediately, call the ````layoutIfNeeded()```` method.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews

Comment: @ArtKirillov yes, but it's hack anyway, otherwise you have this crash. I don't remember already, but probably layoutIfNeeded() did't work.

Answer (score 4):

It's not the best to reloadData everytime (You should use insertItems and deleteItems, and even reloadSections). 
But... after saying that in some cases it's a valid so, you can actually do this:

```
collectionView.dataSource = nil

collectionView.delegate = nil

/*... All changes here. ... */

collectionView.dataSource = self

collectionView.delegate = self

collectionView.reloadData()
```

Comment: I have the same error and setting `dataSource` and `delegate` to `nil` solved the error. In my case I am using `UICollectionView` with two **different** `UICollectionViewLayout`s and I think the **recycling process** has problem with that. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Resetting `UICollectionView`'s layout solved the problem for me:

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
collectionView?.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

Answer (score 4):

Calling `invalidateLayout` did not prevent the crash in my case. (It worked if the number of items in the collection view increased but not if it decreased). Context: I have a UICollectionView inside a UITableViewCell and when the table cell is re-used I reset the delegates of the collectionView. I fixed the problem not by invalidating the cache but by RECREATING the layout object any time I reset the delegate, then calling reloadData():

```
foo.dataSource = newDataSource
foo.delegate = newDelegate
foo.fixLayoutBug()
foo.reloadData()

func fixLayoutBug() {
    let oldLayout = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    let newLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    newLayout.estimatedItemSize = oldLayout.estimatedItemSize
    newLayout.footerReferenceSize = oldLayout.footerReferenceSize
    newLayout.headerReferenceSize = oldLayout.headerReferenceSize
    newLayout.itemSize = oldLayout.itemSize
    newLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = oldLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing
    newLayout.minimumLineSpacing = oldLayout.minimumLineSpacing
    newLayout.scrollDirection = oldLayout.scrollDirection
    newLayout.sectionFootersPinToVisibleBounds = oldLayout.sectionFootersPinToVisibleBounds
    newLayout.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = oldLayout.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds
    newLayout.sectionInset = oldLayout.sectionInset
    newLayout.sectionInsetReference = oldLayout.sectionInsetReference
    collectionViewLayout = newLayout
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was changing the NSlayoutConstraint constant

```
self.collectionViewContacts.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }


            self.collectionViewContacts.reloadData()
```

solved the issue

Answer (score 2):

I had the problem using [RxDataSources](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxDataSources) with `RxCollectionViewSectionedAnimatedDataSource` and solved it by combining two answers. I have to `invalidateLayout()` when reactively reload my collection:

```
    ...
    .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: [])
    .do(onNext: { [weak self] _ in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self?.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
            self?.collectionView.layoutSubviews()
        }
    }).drive(collectionView.rx.items(dataSource: collectionController.dataSource))
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

and  clear `cache` array(s) in `prepare()` layout method. Here is the code:

```
override func prepare() {
    super.prepare()
    cache.removeAll()
    guard let collectionView = collectionView,
        collectionView.numberOfSections > 0,
        let delegate = delegate else {
        return
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your scroll position and fix the crash you can use this:

```
collectionView.reloadData()
let context = collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidationContext(forBoundsChange: collectionView.bounds)
context.contentOffsetAdjustment = CGPoint.zero
collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout(with: context)
```

Comment: Why was my answer down-voted? I know for a fact that this helps

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar issue while showing-hiding collection view using animated constraints change. My solution is based on existing answers.

```
self.filtersCollectionView.reloadData()
if isNeedToUpdateConstraint {
    filtersCollectionViewHeightLayoutConstraint.constant = updatedHeight
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
        self.view.setNeedsLayout()
    }, completion: { completion in
        if completion {
            self.filtersCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well. In my case there was a custom `UICollectionViewLayout` applied to the collection view & the problem was that it had stale data for the number of cells that should be displayed. That's definitely something you can check on when you see `UICollectionView received layout attributes for a cell with an index path that does not exist`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by recreating the `collectionViewLayout` before calling `reloadData()`

The issue was probably related to me having a separate instance for the `dataSource` (i.e. not the view controller holding the collectionView), and when swapping datasource, the crash could appear.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well, but it was because my `UICollectionViewDataSource` changed, and I didn't call `-[UICollectionView reloadData]`. In my case, I had the following data structure:

```
struct Bar { let name: String }
struct Foo { let name: String; let bars: [Bar] }
```

I had two `UICollectionView`s: one for `Foo`s and one for `Bar`s. In my `-collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:`, I had the following:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  if (collectionView == self.fooCollectionView) {
    self.selectedFoo = self.foos[indexPath.row];
    [self.barCollectionView reloadData];
    self.fooCollectionView.hidden = YES;
    self.barCollectionView.hidden = NO;
  } else if (collectionView == self.barCollectionView) {
    // do some stuff with the selected bar

    self.selectedFoo = nil;
    // This -reloadData call fixed my error. I thought I didn't
    // need it since my UICollectionView was hidden
    [self.barCollectionView reloadData];
    self.barCollectionView.hidden = YES;
    self.fooCollectionView.hidden = NO;
  }
}
```

Without the `-reloadData` call, I would see the crash when I rotated the device.

Answer (score 0):

After spending two days of time, the below code solved the issue. Before loading a collectionview write the below code.

```
let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
collecView.collectionViewLayout = flowLayout 
collecView.delegate = self
collecView.dataSource = self
collecView.reloadData()
```

Then the crash will be resolved, but you will find issue in collectionview cells, as the cells are compressed or not as per your design. Then just a line of code after **scrolldirection** line

```
flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 92, height: 100)
```

With the above line of code, you can adjust you collectionview cell layout.

I hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was changing the constant of NSLayoutConstraint none of the above solution worked for me. thanks to @jeff ayan whose answer gave me the hint. I solved the problem with this code

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    imagesCollectionHeight.constant = 100 // changing collectionview height constant
    imageContainerWidth.constant = 100  //changing width constant of some view
    self.layoutIfNeeded() // this line did the trick for me
}
```

Hope it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

The following made it for me:

```
[self.collectionView reloadData];
[self.collectionView layoutIfNeeded];
```

This code seems to force collectionView to scroll to the first cell before reloading data, what seems to cause the error in my case.