# UICollectionView Crash on reloadData

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

UICollectionview is loaded with simple cells and there is a simple int variable for calculating the number of items in the section.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return viewCount
}
```

When the value of viewCount (initially at 45) is changed to a lower number (say 12) the app crashes.

This is error message to update the item count:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UICollectionView received layout attributes for a cell with an index path that does not exist: <NSIndexPath: 0x17402fbe0> {length = 2, path = 0 - 12}'
```

I tried reloading data and invalidating the cache as well as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39867325/ios-10-bug-uicollectionview-received-layout-attributes-for-a-cell-with-an-index). This didn't help. I also tried reloading the indexSet before invalidating the cache. That didn't help either.

```
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if textField == countTextField {
            viewCount = Int(textField.text!)!
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
            let indexSet = IndexSet(integer: 0)

//            collectionView.reloadSections(indexSet)
            collectionView.reloadData()
            collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
        }

        return true
    }
```

I use 2 custom `UICollectinViewLayout` and I also set `shouldInvalidateLayout` to be true. 
Any help?

**Update**

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "DemoCell", for: indexPath) as! DemoCollectionViewCell
        cell.indexLabel.text = "\(indexPath.item + 1)"

        return cell
    }

    @IBAction func showLayout1(_ sender: Any) {
        currentLayout = DemoACollectionViewLayout()
        animateLayout()
    }

    @IBAction func showLayout2(_ sender: Any) {
        currentLayout = DemoBCollectionViewLayout()
        animateLayout()
    }

    func animateLayout() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) { [weak self] value in
            guard let `self` = self else { return }
            self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
            self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = self.currentLayout!
        }
    }
```

Here is the [sample](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0gx8pY0asBmbmxET29URzIxd0k) project.

**Update**:
   I have updated to use an dataObject to reload the `UICollectionView` but the cache in UICollectionViewLayout is not being cleared when I invalidate.

Comment: please post the rest of your collection view delegate methods

Comment: why not using arrays to populate table?

Comment: This is just a demo layout and no need datasource.Just empty cells with a label that tracks the index

Comment: So you just want to have collection view with label printing index ?

Comment: @TusharSharma yes

Comment: @SiddharthanAsokan but your question seems like you trying something else.

Comment: The issue is related to reloading data with decreased `viewCount` value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cache must be cleared when the number of items for the collectionView has changed.

```
guard let views = collectionView?.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)
            else {
    cache.removeAll()
    return
}

if views != cache.count {
    cache.removeAll()
}

if cache.isEmpty { 
   //Layout attributes
}
```