# RxSwift - UICollectionView does not update after updating

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I have a UITabBarController with 2 controllers.

1. In the first VC user have a list of articles. A user can add some article to favourite (realm database)
2. The second VC it is a list with realm query (favourite article).
   When 2 controllers created (user tap to both of them), and in the first VC add article to favourite in the second collectionView does not show new item.

My favouriteVC collectionView binding

```
 private func setupBinds(){
    self.favArticleCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "PreviewItemVCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: PreviewItemVCell.identifier)

    viewModel
        .articlesSubject
        .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
        .bind(to:
        self.favArticleCollectionView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: PreviewItemVCell.identifier, cellType: PreviewItemVCell.self)) { (item, article,cell) in
            cell.article =  article
    }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

and my favouriteViewModel which make a query from db

```
class FavouriteViewModel {
let articlesSubject: PublishSubject<[ArticleModel]> = PublishSubject()



func fetchDateFromDb(){
    print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!)
    let articleList = DatabaseManager.shared.getAllArticle().toArray()

    articlesSubject.onNext(articleList)
}}
```

Problem: When the controller has created, he does not update. How I can update it?

Comment: When do you trigger `fetchDateFromDb`? If it's trigger only once when the secondVC is loaded, then you won't get new data when user add to favourite. You could either refetch when appearing, or trigger `fetchDateFromDb` when adding / removing elements to the favourite.

Comment: @Ben I call it at the viewWillAppear method and it is always the last date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my custom layout for collection view.
It is the right answer
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53275711/error-uicollectionview-received-layout-attributes-for-a-cell-with-an-index-path)